# cakephp 2 complex find all condition

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a Notifications table with the following fields :

**| id | event_id | user_id | status | created |**

There are 5 different status(0,1,2,3,4). The `event_id` and `user_id` are foreign keys of their respective tables.

What I need to find is all the data of Notifications table for the logged in user with an exception :

> only when the `status` equals 1 for a particular `event_id`, it should only display the latest data

For example, if the table has following data :
[image]

I need to display data with `id` 1, 3 and 4 because `id` 2 is not the latest data of the `event_id` 100 with `status` 1.

```
$this->Notifications->find('all', array( 
   'conditions' => array(
       'Notification.user_id' => $user_id, //$user_id is the logged in user's id
   )
));
```

Neither can I use `group` by `event_id` in the find because a particular event may have various status nor can I `group` by `status` because I have various events.

How can this be solved? Can this be solved without using foreach and if conditions and new array appending?

Comment: I think you'd be better off if you'd discuss this problem with respect to bare SQL, ie ask the SQL experts, and then try to port possible solutions to CakePHP. It sounds as if you're looking for a combination of conditional grouping and a greatest-n-per-group select.

Comment: If you need to get only the `created` field, you can use `MAX(created)` in the field list and group by event_id and  status.